# Error in classify_model (package RTextTools)

Tags: r

I get an error with the package RTextTools when trying to use the function classify_model:

```
svm1_classify <- classify_model(container, "svm1")
Error in classify_model(container, "svm1") : object "results_table" not found
```

I get this error even when analysing the USCongress data (shipped with the package itself).

I believe that the problem is in the function train_model, but I cannot get it to work.

This is the full code I am using:

```
data(USCongress)

doc_matrix <- create_matrix(USCongress$text, language="english", removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, removeSparseTerms=.998)

container <- create_container(doc_matrix, USCongress$major, trainSize=1:4000, testSize=4001:nrow(USCongress), virgin=FALSE)

svm1 <- train_model(container, "SVM")

svm1_classify <- classify_model(container, "svm1")
```

Comment: How about `svm1_classify <- classify_model(container, svm1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `classify_model`, the `model` must be an object, not a string. Thus:

```
svm1_classify <- classify_model(container, svm1)
```